# Não dá pra fechar pergunta com recompensa ativa... por que mesmo?

Tags: suporte

Descobri hoje que se uma pergunta tiver recompensa ativa, ela não pode ser votada para fechar com qualquer motivo. Simplesmente porque ela tem uma recompensa ativa! A pergunta onde eu descobri isso é essa: [Como posso formatar equações no Word 2013 de forma automática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149498/como-posso-formatar-equa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-no-word-2013-de-forma-autom%c3%a1tica)

Tirando o fato de que a mensagem só é exibida DEPOIS de eu selecionar a opção e clicar em votar (falha de usabilidade), tem algum motivo isso? Pergunto porque dá pra explorar isso pra impedir uma pergunta ruim de ser fechada, não?

> EDIT: É só falar que o problema não é muito comum e... ta dá!
>   [Colocar objetos sobre imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147198/colocar-objetos-sobre-imagem)

Comment: Não posso dar uma resposta aqui agora, mas se ajudar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work e http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199190/140010

Comment: Relacionado [Devemos usar o sistema de gratificação para impedir o fechamento de perguntas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204/devemos-usar-o-sistema-de-gratifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-impedir-o-fechamento-de-perguntas)

Comment: Obrigado senhores. Os links são de grande ajuda. :)

Comment: Concordo com o problema de usabilidade, se é pra impedir, que se avise já de clicar no fechar (ou melhor, desative-se o fechar com um ícone de ? do lado que acione um help, pra quem quiser saber pq tá desativada). Vejo muitas vezes o bônus ser usado basicamente para segurar a questão aberta, e nesses casos, como não posso fechar, resta a negativação (que muitas vezes eu não daria, bastaria fechar). Normalmente elas vão pros meus bookmarks, pra eu lembrar de fechar quando puder.

Comment: @Bacco Eu li as fontes mencionadas pelos colegas bigown e Jorge B. e entendo e concordo com a motivação por trás do mecanismo. O uso mal intencionado é limitado pelo fato de que uma pergunta, mesmo ruim, precisa esperar 2 dias pra poder receber o destaque de uma recompensa. Mas no caso dessa pergunta eu acho que foi um erro honesto do AP (ele mesmo não sabia se o problema era do escopo ou não). Assim, pra justamente evitar as negativações do tipo já-que-não-posso-fechar, eu sinalizei essa pergunta para os moderadores. Se eles acharem que vale a pena desfazer, certamente o farão. :)

Comment: Talvez o problema seja a calibração dos 2 dias para a atividade do nosso site. Escapa bastante coisa por aqui no fim de semana. Com 3 pegaríamos ou uma segunda ou uma sexta obrigatoriamente, mas entendo que talvez haja uma lista de coisas mais importantes.

Comment: @Bacco Pode ser. Mas, como eu disse, me parece que foi um erro honesto. O AP colocou a recompensa porque a pergunta simplesmente não teve atenção suficiente (eu mesmo não tinha visto antes). Dai quando teve, descobriu-se que não fazia parte do escopo, só que a recompensa já estava dada.

Comment: Ah, não me ative à pergunta específica, só comentei baseado na experiência geral. Faltou cuidado meu em avisar isso no comentário inicial. Essa do link eu não votei e nem acho que mereça negativo.

Comment: @Bacco Olha, a ideia de passar de 2 para 3 dias (por causa do final de semana) me parece bem colocada. Talvez valesse a pena alguns testes a esse respeito.

Comment: Tem vários pequenos ajustes nesse sentido que eu sinto falta, mas nem fico metralhando o meta com idéias por uma questão de "problemas maiores em aberto". Talvez em algum momento eu retome isso, em outra "fase" do site. PS: que fique claro que por "metralhando" não passei nem perto de me referir à sua postagem, foi especificamente sobre a hipótese de eu fazer uma separada pra questão dos 3 dias e outros "detalhes menores".

Comment: @LuizVieira não sei se percebeu lá, a não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte, a ideia é não fazer nada. Na verdade nem sei se tem algo que moderadores possam fazer já que nem há essa opção nas nossas ferramentas. Ou seja, é algo raro e que dificilmente causa problema, então é melhor deixar assim e agir conforme for dando. Claro que pode haver um caso que precise mesmo mexer, mas duvido. É complicado ter que ficar mexendo em casos tão excepcionais e de baixo impacto. Provavelemente é muito esforço para pouco resultado.

Comment: @bigown Ué... Eu vi lá que nesses casos deve-se justamente sinalizar para os moderadores. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103 Agora, se é melhor deixar ou não, é outra discussão. Eu particularmente não ligo pra reputação, então não me importaria em perdê-la. Não sei se é o caso do AP. De todos os modos, a minha preocupação são as negativações que o impedimento de fechar pode causar.

Comment: @LuizVieira sinalizar tudo bem, mas não acho que seja o caso de um moderador fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: @bigown Ah, ok. Bom, aí eu já não sei. Eu fiz a minha boa ação. rs

Comment: Importante dizer que um garoto de 2 anos resolveu o clássico problema ético do trem que colidiria e mataria várias pessoas e da sua chance de interferir para matar só uma, que não iria morrer sem sua interferência: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-N_RZJUAQY4

Comment: Reabri essa pergunta, e fechei a antiga como duplicada, porque essa é muito mais geral ao invés de se tratar de um caso específico.

Comment: Acho que ao menos o link da questão mais antiga deveria ter mantido: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4237/remover-pergunta-destaque-aparentemente-abandonada-e-de-baixa-qualidade

Comment: E ainda discordo de marcar a antiga como duplicada... ambas abordam o mesmo assunto e possuem um link para uma pergunta como exemplo..  ficou bem zuado esse critério em inverter qual é a duplicada..

Comment: @DanielOmine o mais importante é ter o conteúdo organizado, agora se uma é duplicata ou a outra é um bocado indiferente. Afinal somos um site colaborativo. :)

Comment: concordo contigo Jorge.. só não concordei com a ação que me pareceu bastante desrespeitosa.. pois eu estava lá comentando "no vazio" feito bobo por ter sido sinalizado por um comentário que o bacco fez lá.. aí quando termino de digitar vejo todos aqui e pá.. retorno lá e está fechado como duplicata..

Comment: @DanielOmine não podes levar esse tipo de coisas a mal, eu antigamente também levava e compreendo-te. As vezes ainda levo... Mas  se há coisa que aprendi neste site é que é mais importante resolver os probelmas que pensar em nós mesmos.

Comment: falando por mim, não estou aqui pensando em mim mesmo. Só disse que foi desrespeitoso... não importo com decisão de escolher qual era duplicada, é indiferente. Mas do jeito que foi feito, sem avisar.... Se tivesse ao menos avisado não teria perdido tempo a toa.. e nem estaria aqui de mimimi.

Comment: pra deixar claro, só por precaução.. não fui eu quem negativou a pergunta... falows

Comment: @LuizVieira Minha opinião que essa da edição é um caso diferente. Acredito que ele colocou sabendo o que está fazendo e com o objetivo certo. Se só perceberam agora que ela está destacada que ela merecia ser fechada é outro problema e não vejo solução melhor que deixar como está. Se tirar o destaque e devolver os pontos terá ganho algum destaque de graça, se tirar o destaque e não devolver os pontos fica quase como estelionato tanto para o AP quanto um possível respondedor que estava preparando uma resposta por causa da recompensa. Se ele não melhorar pode fechar quando terminar o período.

Comment: @bigown Sim, eu concordo, é um caso diferente (e também não acho que merece qualquer consideração de estorno). Só que é o mesmo "problema" de se - bom, no caso, eu - perceber uma pergunta com problemas somente após ela receber destaque. Por isso eu coloquei a edição.

Comment: @bigown É que pra mim parece que nós falhamos como comunidade ao deixar esse tipo de coisa acontecer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recompensa é um assunto que costuma causar desconforto.

Oferecer uma recompensa pode te custar bastante, especialmente se você é novo no site. E normalmente você não tem como recuperar esses pontos - afinal, é o preço que você paga parar ter destaque, aparecer numa seção especial do site, etc.

Responder uma pergunta com recompensa é participar de um jogo diferente do normal do site. Você não está apenas concorrendo contra os outros usuários por uma quantidade ilimitada de reputação, ou um extra de 15 pontos quando sua resposta é aceita. Você está tentando ganhar um prêmio maior, o valor total de recompensa.

Dessa maneira, fechar uma pergunta durante o período de recompensa vai necessariamente frustrar a expectativa de alguém. Ou o autor da pergunta vai ter menos destaque do que pagou pra receber (se a recompensa não for devolvida), ou quem responder perderá a chance de ganhar seu prêmio (se a recompensa for devolvida). Se a pergunta for fechada e depois reaberta, tudo fica ainda mais confuso.

A melhor alternativa, então, é votar para fechar perguntas *antes* que elas ofereçam recompensa (pra isso existe o período de espera), ou esperar até que o período de recompensa acabe, se for necessário (se a pergunta for reaberta, a recompensa não é afetada).

Em casos extremos, moderadores *podem intervir*, devolver a recompensa oferecida e fechar a pergunta mas só em casos muito particulares, por conta de tudo que foi dito acima. Particularmente, só ajo assim em casos em que é extremamente provável que a pergunta acabe sendo removida do site (já que isso acaba cancelando a recompensa de qualquer maneira). Se for possível, o melhor a fazer é editar a pergunta e corrigir quaisquer problemas que ela tenha.

Comment: normalmente não dá tempo de ver ou mesmo advinhar se uma pergunta ruim será colocada como destaque..

Comment: vou apenas colar aqui um comentário que argumentei na pegunta original: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4237/remover-pergunta-destaque-aparentemente-abandonada-e-de-baixa-qualidade

Comment: " Acho que o fato de pagar com os pontos que possui é irrelevante. Afinal pagou para ter o destaque de algo fora de escopo ou passível de fechamento. Fazendo uma analogia: Você obtém licensas da prefeitura para fazer uma apresentação numa praça pública e obviamente pagou taxas. Então na apresentação comete certas contravenções, faz piadas racistas ou alguém aparece nú (apenas exemplo). Imediatamente, a polícia vai pedir para que se retire, independente se pagou ou não. O fato de pagar pelo espaço não dá o direito de infrigir normas. Dá direito ao espaço, mas ainda deve cumprir as normas. "

Comment: Shog9 já sabe falar português? ;)

Comment: @DanielOmine se for comparar certo, teve 2 dias pra fiscalização e ela não apareceu, e aí começa o problema. O que eu reportei foi a regra do site, justamente. Sua observação não gera solução, só debate. A regra é que não fecha com bônus, e a regra é que se paga pelo destaque. Teria que encontrar uma solução sem violar as duas, ou mudar a regra (não estou me opondo tampouco aprovando isso, só reportando). Talvez 2 dias seja pouco pro SOpt.

Comment: @DanielOmine Eu gosto de metáforas. Mas não acho que essa sua é muito justa. Na minha opinião seria mais parecido com o que ocorreu se fosse assim: "Você usou o espaço público, no qual vc já paga taxas como todos, para fazer sua apresentação. Não teve qualquer atenção e ninguém disse que aquele nú era errado. Aí, então, pagou taxas *adicionais*, e alguém vem e lhe diz que o nú não pode." Enfim, eu já aceitei a resposta do Shog9 (muito bom português!), pois a resposta à minha pergunta é essa. Se é justo ou não é outro problema. :)

Comment: Concordo @Bacco. O que eu coloquei é mera observação. Não estou tipo, querendo dizer que tem que ser assim, mas que deveríamos debater. Afinal, acho que a maioria discorda dessa regra, certo? Se somos uma comunidade e chega a ser unânime que ninguem gosta de perguntas ruins ou passíveis de fechamento no destaque, então não poderíamos rever essa norma que evita fechar devido ao bônus?

Comment: quem é esse tal de shog9?

Comment: @DanielOmine [Esse tal de shog9](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6/shog9). :)

Comment: Pus essa musica pra ouvir agora: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw08Py5nz1w

Comment: saquei é tipo um AI Bot.. Mas o que coloquei foi uma analogia e vc distorceu para algo nada a ver com o sentido da analogia;; mas enfim.. deixei claro na resposta acima com menção ao Bacco.

Comment: @DanielOmine ele é um CM tambem. Em teoria, não é "artificial" :)

Comment: @DanielOmine Não é um AI bot, é um humano mesmo. Ele é Community Manager da SE. Sobre a analogia, eu não a "distorci". Eu só fiz outra analogia comparativa, que, como eu disse, é a *minha opinião* do que seria mais justo como analogia.

Comment: Luiz, agora entendi que vc não distorceu, mas fez uma nova versão. E entendi o ponto chave também que é o AP não saber das regras.. Mas aí nao poderia apenas permitir usuários com um certo nível de pontuação a colocar coisas no destaque?

Comment: @DanielOmine É uma ideia. Mas eu não sei se ela seria boa, porque limitaria as opções das pessoas. O AP tinha reputação suficiente para oferecer. Eu só achei que foi um erro honesto da parte dele. Mesmo. Se eu estivesse no lugar dele (e supondo que ele já entendeu onde estava mesmo o problema dele), eu certamente estaria arrependido de ter dado a recompensa. Mas, de todas as formas, os demais têm razão em que isso é algo raro de acontecer, porque em geral se nota os problemas antes da pergunta receber o destaque.

Comment: Entendi. Então onde que dá para ver as perguntas que vão entrar em destaque? Eu nunca vi esse recurso

Comment: @DanielOmine não dá pra ver, mas vc só consegue por bonus depois de 2 dias. Nesses 2 dias a comunidade teria tempo de ver e fechar. Nesse ponto que eu comento que em 2 dias a postagem às vezes passa sem avaliação quando pega fim de semana. Seria caso de fechamento, mas acaba sendo vista por pouca gente, dando tempo de aplicar o bonus.

Comment: Entendi. Não sabia sobre o tempo de 2 dias para aplicar recompensa (bonus).

Comment: Falo um Gabe, @Jorge ;-)

Comment: O ideal é lidar com as perguntas ruins antes delas receberem destaque, @Daniel. Esperar dois dias para lidar com um caso de racismo, é um problema por si só. Além disso, nesse caso as sinalizações de "rude ou ofensivo" fazem mais sentido do que o fechamento.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks, i got it.

Comment: @Bacco Como um dos sites mais movimentados da rede, acho difícil que 2 dias não sejam suficientes pro SOpt. Mesmo durante o fim de semana, nosso tráfego é alto suficiente pra tomar conta de casos assim. Obviamente não temos movimento suficiente pra evitar *todos* os casos assim (senão esse post não existia), mas definitivamente temos tamanho suficiente pra não justificar uma mudança por causa de casos ocasionais...

Comment: @Gabe Não sei se é pelo fato de eu ficar um bocado de tempo no site em horários variados, mas minha percepção é de que não sejam tão ocasionais assim (são ocasionais, mas não "raros"). De qq forma, eu já havia reconhecido que tal alteração está longe de ser importante ou relevante em vista do conjunto todo. Acho que mesmo um teste para avaliar isso seria mais caro do que o retorno no caso de alteração.

Comment: @Shog9 ahahahahahahah

Comment: considerando tudo, acho que não ´precisa mudar nada.. um caso ou outro vai passar despercebido e pode ser tolerado.